# Proving that vector is in Span when coefficient matrix has no solution

Tags: linear-algebra, matrix-equations

When finding out if a vector $v_4$ exists in $Span(v_1,v_2,v_3)$ I am first building an linear system of equations that in a way that solve

$$
s*v_1 + r * v_2 + t * v_3 = v_4 
$$

s,r,t are elements of the real numbers.

In my specific example my coefficient matrix solves to the following

$$
    \begin{matrix}
    3 & 0 & 2 & 9 \\
    0 & 3 & -1 & 3 \\
    0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
    \end{matrix}
\\
$$

Implying that this system has infinite solutions. My question is, does that imply that $v_4$ is not in that Span, or can I choose my last variable t freely such as $t = \lambda$ and continue solving the system?

Comment: $v_4$ is in the span if it can be expressed as a linear combination of the other vectors. You’ve shown that this can be done in an infinite number of ways.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes it means that $v_4$ is in the span, notably that means that $v_4$ can be expressed as a linear combination of two vectors, for example $v_1$ and $v_2$, thus we can fix the coefficient $t$ for $v_3$ to zero (or to any arbitrary number) and solve for $s$ and $r$.